# Pattern Matching and auto-complete for two arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, pattern-matching

Let's say i have an array:

```
[0, -2, 0,  0,  -3,  0,  -1,  0,  1,  0,  3,  0,  2,  0,  0,  0]
```

And I want to see if it can fit the pattern below:

```
[1, 1, 1 , 0, 0 , 0 , 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
```

Where 1 means that the number is unique and 0 means that all of those numbers match.  Here we would have a match, if I arranged like so:

```
[-3, -2, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  2,  3,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0];
```

Is there any Matlab function for this or must I think up my own way?

Comment: I arranged the first array so that all the numbers were different where 1 was present in the second array. 0 means that all those numbers were the same.  I could have put any unique numbers in that 1 position.

Comment: Are all numbers that are not zeros always unique?

Comment: Yes and there are never more than 6.

Comment: In your example the result is also sorted, is this necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it feels like an **interpolation problem**, so I think the following will be a robust solution:

```
%// data
A = [0, -2, 0,  0,  -3,  0,  -1,  0,  1,  0,  3,  0,  2,  0,  0,  0]
B = [1, 1, 1 , 0, 0 , 0 , 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

%// input data for interpolation
x  = 1:numel(A)
v = A;
%// query points
mask = logical(B) & ~logical(A);
xq = find( mask )
%// interpolation
vq = interp1(x(~mask),v(~mask),xq,'linear','extrap')

%// output
out = A.*B;
out(xq) = vq
```

---

```
out =

    -3   -2   -1    0    0    0    0    0    1    2    3    0    0    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said in the comments that you can put any unique numbers where 1s are, and all numbers, that are not zeros, are always unique, so I think following will do it:

```
A = [0, -2,  0,  0,  -3,  0,  -1,  0,  1,  0,  3,  0,  2,  0,  0,  0];
B = [1, 1, 1 , 0, 0 , 0 , 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

B(B==1)= A(A~=0)
```

which gives this:

```
B =
-2  -3  -1   0   0   0   0   0   1   3   2   0   0   0   0   0
```

to match the exact output of yours in the question, you can use the following:

```
A = [0, -2,  0,  0,  -3,  0,  -1,  0,  1,  0,  3,  0,  2,  0,  0,  0];
B = [1, 1, 1 , 0, 0 , 0 , 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

A=sort(A);
B(B==1)= A(A~=0)
```

which gives this:

```
B =
-3  -2  -1   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   3   0   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

```
ind = logical([1, 1, 1 , 0, 0 , 0 , 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);
```

You can write:

```
B = zeros(size(ind)); % only if the zeros at the end of 'B' are important    
B(ind) = nonzeros(A)
```

So you use `ind` as logical index to order the elements that are not `0` in `A`, to get:

```
B =

  -2  -3  -1   0   0   0   0   0   1   3   2   0   0   0   0   0
```

if you also want it sorted (as in your example), replace the last line with:

```
B(ind) = nonzeros(sort(A))
```